# Failure when bootstrapping etcd cluster using DNS discovery + Consul

Tags: consul, etcd

I'm trying to bootstrap an etcd cluster using DNS discovery. I rely on Consul to update DNS record.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
etcd \
--name kubemaster-1 \
--discovery-srv k8s-cluster.etcd-registration.service.mydatacenter.consul \
--initial-advertise-peer-urls http://kubemaster-1.node.mydatacenter.consul:2380 \
--initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-1 \
--initial-cluster-state new \
--advertise-client-urls http://kubemaster-1.node.mydatacenter.consul:2379 \
--listen-client-urls http://172.16.8.118:2379 \
--listen-peer-urls http://172.16.8.118:2380
```

DNS seems to be correctly configured:

```
dig +noall +answer SRV _etcd-server._tcp.k8s-cluster.etcd-registration.service.mydatacenter.consul
_etcd-server._tcp.k8s-cluster.etcd-registration.service.mydatacenter.consul. 0 IN SRV   1 1 2379 kubemaster-3.node.mydatacenter.consul.
_etcd-server._tcp.k8s-cluster.etcd-registration.service.mydatacenter.consul. 0 IN SRV   1 1 2379 kubemaster-1.node.mydatacenter.consul.
_etcd-server._tcp.k8s-cluster.etcd-registration.service.mydatacenter.consul. 0 IN SRV   1 1 2379 kubemaster-2.node.mydatacenter.consul.
```

For info the node is also correctly resolved:

```
root@kubemaster-1:/tmp#dig +short kubemaster-1.node.mydatacenter.consul
172.16.8.118
root@kubemaster-1:/tmp#
```

But I got the following error:

```
root@kubemaster-1:/tmp# etcd --name kubemaster-1 \
> --discovery-srv k8s-cluster.etcd-registration.service.mydatacenter.consul \
> --initial-advertise-peer-urls http://kubemaster-1.node.mydatacenter.consul:2380 \
> --initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-1 \
> --initial-cluster-state new \
> --advertise-client-urls http://kubemaster-1.node.mydatacenter.consul:2379 \
> --listen-client-urls http://172.16.8.118:2379 \
> --listen-peer-urls http://172.16.8.118:2380
2019-01-09 12:33:14.220716 I | etcdmain: etcd Version: 3.3.9
2019-01-09 12:33:14.220751 I | etcdmain: Git SHA: fca8add78
2019-01-09 12:33:14.220758 I | etcdmain: Go Version: go1.10.3
2019-01-09 12:33:14.220770 I | etcdmain: Go OS/Arch: linux/amd64
2019-01-09 12:33:14.220780 I | etcdmain: setting maximum number of CPUs to 2, total number of available CPUs is 2
2019-01-09 12:33:14.220792 W | etcdmain: no data-dir provided, using default data-dir ./kubemaster-1.etcd
2019-01-09 12:33:14.220838 I | embed: listening for peers on http://172.16.8.118:2380
2019-01-09 12:33:14.220867 I | embed: listening for client requests on 172.16.8.118:2379
2019-01-09 12:33:14.236017 N | embed: got bootstrap from DNS for etcd-server at 0=https://kubemaster-2.node.mydatacenter.consul:2379
2019-01-09 12:33:14.236033 N | embed: got bootstrap from DNS for etcd-server at 1=https://kubemaster-3.node.mydatacenter.consul:2379
2019-01-09 12:33:14.236048 N | embed: got bootstrap from DNS for etcd-server at 2=https://kubemaster-1.node.mydatacenter.consul:2379
2019-01-09 12:33:14.236069 N | embed: got bootstrap from DNS for etcd-server at 3=http://kubemaster-2.node.mydatacenter.consul:2379
2019-01-09 12:33:14.236080 N | embed: got bootstrap from DNS for etcd-server at 4=http://kubemaster-3.node.mydatacenter.consul:2379
2019-01-09 12:33:14.236089 N | embed: got bootstrap from DNS for etcd-server at 5=http://kubemaster-1.node.mydatacenter.consul:2379
2019-01-09 12:33:14.236162 C | etcdmain: error setting up initial cluster: cannot find local etcd member "kubemaster-1" in SRV records
```

I guess I missed somethig, but can't what.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Renaud

Answer (score 0):

I find out the issue, I made a mistake when I register the service in consul I configure port 2379 instead of 2380.